# Joint probability function of a fair dice where one random variable is geometric and the other is counting all 1s until 6 is achieved

Tags: probability, random-variables, dice

A fair dice is been tossed until "6" is achieved.
Let Y be the random variable stating the number of tosses required.
Let X be the random variable stating the  number of tosses where "1" was achieved until "6" is achieved.
What is the joint distribution of X and Y?

What I have tried to do

First I know that
$$
X\sim G(\frac{1}{6})
$$

$$
P_{X|Y}(x|y) = \frac{P_{X,Y}(x,y)}{P_{Y}(y)} \Leftrightarrow  {P_{Y}(y)}*P_{X|Y}(x|y) = P_{X,Y}(x,y)
$$

So from here I tried to find the probability function of $$P_{X|Y}(x|y)$$

I created a table
$$
\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline k & P_{X|Y}(x|y=k) \\ \hline 1 & \frac{1}{6} \\ \hline 2 & \frac{1}{6^2}+\frac{4}{6^2} \\ \hline 3 & \frac{1}{6} *((\frac{4}{6})^2 + 2*\frac{4}{6}*\frac{1}{6} + (\frac{1}{6})^2)) \\ \hline  \end{array}
$$

and so on until we get
$$
P_{X|Y}(x|y=k) = \frac{1}{6}*(\frac{4}{6}+\frac{1}{6})^{k-1} = \frac{1}{6}*(\frac{5}{6})^{k-1}
$$
if k=1 thus first throw is 6
if k=2 thus first throw is either 1 or 2-5 but second throw is 6
and so on.
If I sum all the values it helps me to make sure it is indeed a probability function (equals 1)

but then, returning to what we derived from results in

$$
P_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{1}{6^2}*(\frac{5}{6})^{2k-2} 
$$

where $$k=1,2,...$$

The sum on all k values isn't 1, where did i go wrong or maybe i was wrong from the begining?

Sorry for the title, couldn't come up with something short and precise for that

Comment: This is not clear.  What do the entries in your table mean?  $P(X\,|\,Y=k)$ should be a distribution, not a number.  Specifically, for each possible value $X=x$, it represents the probability that it takes $x$ trials to see the first $6$, conditioned on knowing that you see exactly $k$ $1's$ before the first $6$.  Thus, this is $0$ if $x\leq k$ but it is non-zero for infinitely many other values.  What did you mean?

Comment: The entries in the table are: the left column the number of throws until 6 was achieved, the right column is the conditional probability where we know 6 was achieved at the k'th toss.

Comment: Be careful with your conditional probabilities. For example, $P(X =1 | Y = 1)$ is $1/5$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog isn't it 0 because if we throw the dice only 1 time and get y (Y=1) then the number 1 can't be achieved because we only tossed 1 time?

Comment: @eladgl I was assuming $Y$ doesn't count the final 6 roll.

Comment: In my prior comment, I think I switched $X,Y$, but the confusion still remains.  What does $P(X\,|\,Y=3)$ mean, exactly?  How is it that you think it is independent of the value of the random variable $X$?

Comment: @lulu
it means the probability of all the number of times 1 was achieved in the first two throws knowing we got 6 at the third row

Comment: What does "the probability of all the number of times..." mean?  To stress:  What $P(X\,|\,Y=3)$ actually means is "the probability distribution of $X$ given that $Y=3$. " Given that $Y=3$, so the first $6$ was observed on the third trial (right?), then there were two prior trials which might or might not have been $1$.  Thus, in this case, $X$ might be any of $\{0,1,2\}$ so you need to list *three* probabilities, not just one.

Comment: You don't seem to have a concept of what the possible outcomes of this random process are. You could have $Y=1,$ in which case you must have $X=0,$ correct? But you could have $Y=2,$ in which case $X$ might be $0$ or $1.$ So now we have three events already: first event $Y=1,X=0$; second event $Y=2,X=0,$; third event $Y=2,X=1.$ Each of those events must have a probability. What do you think those probabilities are? When you add up "the sum on all $k$ values," how does that count all three of these probabilities? (And the three additional event probabilities when $Y=3$, etc.)

Comment: I think that i did list 3 over there i just organized it
$$
(\frac{4}{6})^2$$, is the probability first two were not 1 or 6
$$(\frac{1}{6})^2$$, is the probability first two were 1
$$(\frac{2*1*4}{6*6})$$, is the probability first was 1 second wasn't 1 or 6 and the other way around
And the outer $$\frac{1}{6}$$ is all the thirs toss that we did get 6
$$

Comment: Also, just look your equation, $P_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{1}{6^2}*(\frac{5}{6})^{2k-2}.$ How does the $k$ on the right-hand side relate to anything on the left-hand side? There is no logical connection. That is one reason you aren't getting correct results, you're using a meaningless equation.

Comment: @DavidK, look at the table I showed about where k=3, i did take in all x=0,1,2 where we threw 3 times. what i meant by adding all the k's is that a probability function should sum to 1 where it does not do it there. maybe i was wrong at all and i might be talking nonsense (am a student afterall) if you know how to solve it i would like your help :)

Comment: Your table also doesn't make any sense, for the same reasons as before. You have written numbers under the heading $P_{X,Y}(x\mid y=k)$, but $P_{X,Y}(x\mid y=k)$ is not a number for any given value of $k$. Instead, $P_{X,Y}(x\mid y=k)$ is a number for a given value of $k$ **and** $x.$ You didn't show any values of $x$ in the table. If your heading in the table was meant to represent the **sum** of all the $P_{X,Y}(x\mid y=k)$ values for all possible $x$ values, you have not shown in any coherent way why we should believe this.

Comment: And I realize you are a student, so these criticisms are meant as advice on how to approach (or not approach) a math problem. One piece of advice is, make sure that what you write says **exactly** what you meant it to say when someone else reads it. That means, use the standard notations in standard ways, not just as your own personal memory aids. Second, don't do things in bigger chunks than you are ready for, and if things are not adding up, try breaking them down into smaller steps, being **very** explicit about what you do at each step.

Comment: For example, the value $\frac16(\frac56)^{k-1}$ that you worked out is in fact the correct value of $P_Y(y=k).$ Of course that says little about either $P_{X\mid Y}$ or $P_{X,Y},$ in fact it says nothing about $X$ at all, which would have been clear if you had used the correct notation. This is why details matter. And then you squared the value $\frac16(\frac56)^{k-1}$ for some reason which is completely unclear, and of course that doesn't add up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is the function $p(x,y)$ that gives the probability that $X = x$ and $Y = y$. That is, $p(x,y) = P(X = x\cap Y= y)$. We know from conditional probabilities that $P(X = x\cap Y= y) = P(X = x | Y= y)P(Y = y)$ and $P(X = x\cap Y= y) = P(Y = y|X=x)P(X=x)$. Since $P(Y= y)$ is much easier to find than $P(X=x)$, we'll use the first form.

$Y$ clearly follows a geometric distribution with success probability $1/6$. This gives $P(Y = y) = 5^{y-1}/6^y$

For a fixed value $Y=y$, each of the $y-1$ rolls prior to it has an equal chance to be any of the numbers $1$ through $5$, which means a $1/5$ chance to be $1$. Therefore, given $Y=y$, $X$ follows a binomial distribution with $y-1$ trials and success probability $1/5$. This allows us to find $P(X=x | Y=y) = \binom{y-1}{x}4^{y-1-x}/5^{y-1}$.

We now use these together to find the joint distribution $p(x,y)$:
$$
p(x,y) = P(X=x|Y=y)P(Y=y) = \left[\binom{y-1}{x}\frac{4^{y-1-x}}{5^{y-1}}\right]\left[\frac{5^{y-1}}{6^y}\right] =\binom{y-1}{x}\frac{4^{y-1-x}}{6^y}.
$$
As a sanity check, [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5BBinomial%5By-1%2Cx%5D4%5E%28y-1-x%29%2F6%5Ey%2C%7By%2C1%2CInfinity%7D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2Cy-1%7D%5D) tells me that these probabilities do sum to $1$.